# В Opera 10 не поддерживается $.getScript

Tags: jquery, opera

В Opera 10 не подключается /js/all.js, а в Opera 12 нормально. Как исправить? Или может естсь другое кроссбраузерное решение?

```
$.get('/', function(data) {
 $.getScript('/js/all.js?'+Math.random());
});
```

Comment: Видимо не поддерживается только у вас)) Что дебаггер пишет?

Comment: @lampa, пустота.. А как иначе можно подключать js файл через js :D?

Comment: @ModaL через что смотрите? Я, как помню, однажды также ступил, пока не заглянул во вкладку "Сеть" в firebug. Магическим образом сервер отдавал 403, хотя когда просто вызывал через строку браузера - всё ок)

Comment: @lampa, Tools -> Advanced -> Error Console

Но Вы не забывайте, что это Opera 10, а не 12. Там даже border-radius не поддерживается :)

Comment: @lampa, ну что? :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Только что проверил на Opera 10 Beta, всё отлично работает.

Также можно проверить на страничке документации: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/

Проверяйте свой код на наличие ошибок.